# Want to give some suggestions to a user about professional education. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

A new user posted [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124670/can-some-one-please-share-guide-references-resources-for-network-security-te).

While I agree with Matthew, in that this question is off-topic, I would like to add some references which can be useful for the OP.

However, I don't think it would be fine to add in a comment product recommendations, since they are off-topic. Am I right?

If so, could I create a chatroom and invite the OP to talk about this, or is it frowned upon, since it is off topic?

Comment: Discussing things like this in a chatroom is actually fine, however a new user doesn't have enough rep to access chat, so for this type of scenario, it's unfortunately not an option.